# Making custom admin generator actions look like built-in one

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to make my custom admin generator actions have the same CSS as the built-in ones so my entire backend app has a consistent look and feel. Preferably, I could do this globally rather than applying the style to each of my custom actions individually.

For example, if I create a new action `foo` in a module `bar`, then I go to `myapp.com/frontend_dev.php/backend/bar/foo`, the page I see is completely unstyled even though `bar/index`, `bar/new` and all the other default actions are styled the way I would expect. I want it to share the styles of the rest of the admin-generated pages.

Does anyone know how to do this?

(I'm using symfony 1.4 and Doctrine.)

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this in the past i to simply copy the generated HTML from an admin generator page.

Do this easily with Firebug in Firefox - in the inspector right click the main admin container and click 'copy html'.

Paste it into your template file and add in your data items to the tables.

Also, you will need to include the symfony admin generator css file, which you can find by looking at the paths in a standard admin gen page.